# How to access methods of imported PCL library in Xamarin ios project

Tags: xamarin.ios, printer-control-language

i have imported a PCL library into my Xamarin IOS project. I can access the class but not the methods under it

1. I tried by making the method "static" in oder to access it Classsname.methodName but it doesnt work
2. I have tried to create an instance of the class and tried to access the method, this also doesnt work

Any help will be appreciated !!

Comment: Please try to add some of your class and method definition in your question. Meanwhile, make sure your method is public.

Comment: Thanks!
I just found out that, when creating the method in the class, it had private identifier. I just changed that to public and now its fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we don't specify accessibility level, Class is `internal` by defalut , method is `Private`by default, so as  MilanG  suggested, you should make the method `Public` if you want to access it.

#### Without `public`

```
public class Class1
{
    void test() {

    }
}
```

[image]

#### With `public`

```
public class Class1
{
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

[image]

PS:If it still doesn't work, try to clean and rebuild the PCL library.

Comment: Thanks!
I just found out that, when creating the method in the class, it had private identifier. I just changed that to public and now its fine

Comment: @Assegd Thanks!!